# One code and deferent result in android2.2 vs android4.2

Tags: java, android, android-gridview

In a big project i have below codes that run step is
first GalleryMeno runs and then GalleryActivityMain

`GalleryMeno.java`

```
public class GalleryMeno  extends Activity{

private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.gallary_farhad1 ,
        R.drawable.gallary_farhad2,
        R.drawable.gallary_naser ,
        R.drawable.gallary_mehdi ,
        R.drawable.gallary_other ,
        R.drawable.gallary_old ,
        R.drawable.gallary_amir ,
        R.drawable.gallary_bazikonan
};

private String[] name = {
        "gallary_farhad1",
        "gallary_farhad2",
        "gallary_naser",
        "gallary_mehdi",
        "gallary_other",
        "gallary_old",
        "gallary_amir",
        "gallary_bazikonan"
};

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery_meno_activity);

    TextView titleName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_name);
    titleName.setText("گالری تصاویر");


    //found width of Screen for Gridview
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
    int densityX = display.getWidth();  

    Button btnUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);
    btnUpdate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    Button backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backward);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-g

            finish();
        }
    });

    GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridViewSms);
    grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext(), densityX, mThumbIds));

    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position ,
                long id) {

            Intent MainGallery = new Intent(GalleryMeno.this , GalleryActivityMain.class);
            MainGallery.putExtra("position", position);
            MainGallery.putExtra("title", name[position]);

            startActivity(MainGallery);     
        }
    });
}
}
```

`ImageAdapter .java`

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
 private Context mContext;
 private int widthOfScrren;
 public Integer[] mThumbIds;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c,int ScrrenSize,Integer[] mThumbIds){
        mContext = c;
        widthOfScrren=ScrrenSize;
        this.mThumbIds = mThumbIds;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }    

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        final int w;
        if ( widthOfScrren == 0 )
            w =  75;
        else
            w = widthOfScrren/3;
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(w,w));
        return imageView;
    }   
}
```

`GalleryActivityMain.java`

```
public class GalleryActivityMain extends Activity {
   public static Integer[] ImageGroup1 = {
       R.drawable.farhad01,
       R.drawable.farhad02,
       R.drawable.farhad03,
       R.drawable.farhad04,
       R.drawable.farhad05,
       R.drawable.farhad06,
       R.drawable.farhad07,
       R.drawable.farhad08,
       R.drawable.farhad09,
       R.drawable.farhad10,
       R.drawable.farhad11,
       R.drawable.farhad12,
       R.drawable.farhad13,
       R.drawable.farhad14,
       R.drawable.farhad15,
       R.drawable.farhad16

    };
   public static Integer[] ImageGroup2 = {
       R.drawable.farhad17,
       R.drawable.farhad18,
       R.drawable.farhad19,
       R.drawable.farhad20,
       R.drawable.farhad21,
       R.drawable.farhad22,
       R.drawable.farhad23,
       R.drawable.farhad24,
       R.drawable.farhad25,
       R.drawable.farhad26,
       R.drawable.farhad27,
       R.drawable.farhad28,
       R.drawable.farhad29,
       R.drawable.farhad30,
       R.drawable.farhad31,
       R.drawable.farhad32,
       R.drawable.farhad33

   };   

   public static Integer[] ImageGroup3 = {  
       R.drawable.naser01,
       R.drawable.naser02,
       R.drawable.naser03,
       R.drawable.naser04,
       R.drawable.naser05,
       R.drawable.naser06,
       R.drawable.naser07,
       R.drawable.naser08,
       R.drawable.naser09,
       R.drawable.naser10,
       R.drawable.naser11,
       R.drawable.naser12,
       R.drawable.naser13,
       R.drawable.naser14,
       R.drawable.naser15,
       R.drawable.naser16,
       R.drawable.naser17
   };

   public static Integer[] ImageGroup4 = {
       R.drawable.mehdi01,
       R.drawable.mehdi02,
       R.drawable.mehdi03,
       R.drawable.mehdi04,
       R.drawable.mehdi05,
       R.drawable.mehdi06,
       R.drawable.mehdi07,
       R.drawable.mehdi08,
       R.drawable.mehdi09,
       R.drawable.mehdi10,
       R.drawable.mehdi11,
       R.drawable.mehdi12,
       R.drawable.mehdi13,
       R.drawable.mehdi14,
       R.drawable.mehdi15,
       R.drawable.mehdi16,
       R.drawable.mehdi17
   };

   public static Integer[] ImageGroup5 = {
       R.drawable.other01,
       R.drawable.other02,
       R.drawable.other03,
       R.drawable.other04,
       R.drawable.other05,
       R.drawable.other06,
       R.drawable.other07,
       R.drawable.other08,
       R.drawable.other09,
       R.drawable.other10,
       R.drawable.other11,
       R.drawable.other12,
       R.drawable.other13,
       R.drawable.other14,
       R.drawable.other15,
       R.drawable.other16,
   };

 public static Integer[] ImageGroup6 = {

       R.drawable.old01,
       R.drawable.old02,
       R.drawable.old03,
       R.drawable.old04,
       R.drawable.old05,
       R.drawable.old06,
       R.drawable.old07,
       R.drawable.old08,
       R.drawable.old09,
       R.drawable.old10,
       R.drawable.old11,
       R.drawable.old12,
       R.drawable.old13,
       R.drawable.old14,
       R.drawable.old15,
       R.drawable.old16,
       R.drawable.old17,
       R.drawable.old18,
       R.drawable.old19

   };

   public static Integer[] ImageGroup7 = {

       R.drawable.amir01,
       R.drawable.amir02,
       R.drawable.amir03,
       R.drawable.amir04,
       R.drawable.amir05,
       R.drawable.amir06,
       R.drawable.amir07,
       R.drawable.amir08,
       R.drawable.amir09,
       R.drawable.amir10,
       R.drawable.amir11,
       R.drawable.amir12,
       R.drawable.amir13,
       R.drawable.amir14,
       R.drawable.amir15
   };

   public static Integer[] ImageGroup8 = {
        R.drawable.b1,
        R.drawable.b2,
        R.drawable.b3,
        R.drawable.b4,
        R.drawable.b5,
        R.drawable.b6,
        R.drawable.b7,
        R.drawable.b8,
        R.drawable.b9,
        R.drawable.b10,
        R.drawable.b11,
        R.drawable.b12,
        R.drawable.b13,
        R.drawable.b14,
        R.drawable.b15,
        R.drawable.b16,
        R.drawable.b17,
        R.drawable.b18,
        R.drawable.b19,
        R.drawable.b20
   };

   public static Integer[] SelectedGroup;

private int Global_position;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.galery_activity);

    TextView titleName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_name);

    Intent current = getIntent();
    Global_position=current.getExtras().getInt("position");

    titleName.setText(current.getExtras().getString("title"));      

    Button btnUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);
    btnUpdate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    Button backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backward);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();

        }
    });

    GridView grid=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view_gallery);

    //connect xml_gridView to Class ImageAdapter
    //when we sent 0 to screensize we want to auto generating image independent device
    grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0, getCorrectItem(Global_position)));     

    //set item on click listener
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {

            Intent FullImage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GalleryFullImageView.class);
            /******
             * by below syntax we sent some information by a id 
             * to new intent and on new intent we extract it and use it
            ******/
            FullImage.putExtra("position", position);
            startActivity(FullImage);
        }
    });
}

private Integer[] getCorrectItem(int position)
{
    switch (position) {

    case 0:
        SelectedGroup = ImageGroup1;
        return  ImageGroup1;

    case 1:
        SelectedGroup = ImageGroup2;
        return  ImageGroup2;

    case 2:
        SelectedGroup = ImageGroup3;
        return  ImageGroup3;

    case 3:
        SelectedGroup = ImageGroup4;
        return  ImageGroup4;

    case 4:
        SelectedGroup = ImageGroup5;
        return  ImageGroup5;

    case 5:
        SelectedGroup = ImageGroup6;
        return  ImageGroup6;    

    case 6:
        SelectedGroup = ImageGroup7;
        return  ImageGroup7;    
    case 7:
        SelectedGroup = ImageGroup8;
        return  ImageGroup8;            
    default:
        SelectedGroup = ImageGroup7;
        return ImageGroup7;
    }   
}
}
```

`Mymanifest`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.esteghlaliha"
android:versionCode="8"
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
android:versionName="1.9" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="6"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/esteghlal_big"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.perspolisiha.Esteghlal"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="com.example.perspolisiha.Main"
         android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.rank.Resultshow" 
         android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
         android:screenOrientation="landscape"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>

    <activity android:name="com.example.rank.RankLayout"  
         android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>

    <activity android:name="com.example.perspolisiha.SmsshowActivity"  
         android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>

    <activity android:name="com.example.perspolisiha.GalleryActivityMain"  
         android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>

    <activity android:name="com.example.perspolisiha.GalleryFullImageView" 
         android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" 
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>

    <activity android:name="com.example.perspolisiha.GalleryMeno"
         android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>

    <activity android:name="com.example.tv.TVLayout"  
         android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>

    <activity android:name="com.example.tv.TVResultshow" 
         android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>

    <activity android:name="com.example.bio.BioMainActivity" 
         android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>

    <activity android:name="com.example.bio.BioResultShow" 
         android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>

     <activity android:name="com.example.history.HistoryActivity" 
         android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>

     <activity android:name="com.example.news.NewsActivityMain" 
         android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>

     <activity android:name="com.example.news.ShowDetailActivity" 
         android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>

     <activity android:name="com.example.news.setting" 
         android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>

</application>


</manifest>
```

Case1:When i ran above code in android 2.2 i seen a menu of image that made from gridview
and when i click on every item all image about this item shown.(in this case all result is OK)

Case2:But when I ran same code in android 4.2
by click on item (for view all image about it) my program become exit without any forceClose

for ex: when i click on image `gallary_amir` i expect that a gridview of image from `ImageGroup7`
Why?How i can fix Case2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that you don't receive any force close, thereby no LogCat. What I would say is since you are checking on `Android 4.2` which is `API level 17`, try to make your `android:targetSdkVersion=""` as `17` instead of `16` and see if you receiver any errors in `LogCat`. If you read about [android:targetSdkVersion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target), it says:

`If the API level of the platform is higher than the version declared by your app's targetSdkVersion, the system may enable compatibility behaviors to ensure that your app continues to work the way you expect.`

Android tries to enable those compatibility behaviors when you test on higher version that targeted. There might be some function call or some other thing which got changed in API version 17 and is behaving in appropriately. 
Other point is that try to see in your code that which thing have been depreciated for API 17 and have been used in your code. Using upto date stuff is always recommended.

Hope this helps in some way.